# Jest test function that consumes a promise chain

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise, jestjs

My test is failing to wait to a method that consumes a promise chain inside it.

Here is the method

```
 export class UserService {
  static getUser(): void {
    const isFetching = getUserIsFetching(storeInstance.getState());
    if (isFetching) {
      return;
    }
    storeInstance.dispatch(fetchingUserActionCreator());
    HttpService.get<UserResponse>('/api/auth/user')
      .then(userResponse => {
        console.log('test 1');
        Promise.all([
          HttpService.get<Account>('/api/accounts'),
          HttpService.get<PersonalDetails>('/api/accounts/personal-details'),
        ]).then(responses => {
          console.log('test 2');
          storeInstance.dispatch(fetchingUserSuccessActionCreator(responses));
          console.log('test 3');
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        storeInstance.dispatch(fetchingUserFailActionCreator(error));
      })
  }
}
```

And this is the test

```
test.only('should get the user', async () => {
      await UserService.getUser();
      expect(getSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
      expect(getSpy.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('/api/auth/user');
      expect(getSpy.mock.calls[1][0]).toBe('/api/accounts');
      expect(getSpy.mock.calls[2][0]).toBe('/api/accounts/personal-details');
      expect(storeDispatchSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    });
```

The first for assertations it got it right, the problem is the resolve of the Promise.all. The test never got there.

I added some console logs as you can see, to check if the resolve of the promise all was not called, but no. All the console logs were returned.

Then I added a console log in my test, just after the `await UserService.getUser()`, an this is what was logged after the test.

```
 test 1 
 await finished
 test 2
 test 3
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `return Promise.all(...)` <-- you forgot the return

Answer (score 0):

It is probably you have not include the Promise in the file.